# 2 Modules with same Variables

Tags: ruby

I have a issue where I have 2 modules having different names but same variables names. now even if I include the second module in the class, it still picks up the variable value from first Module.

```
# FILE name ABC.rb (path C:/my/ABC.rb)
module one
  a= 10
end

# FILE name DEF.rb (path C:/my/DEF.rb)
module two
   a=15
end

# FILE name MyClass.rb
require C:/my/DEF.rb

Class MyClass
  include two

  def  setup
    puts a
  end
end
```

result is

```
10
```

Please help, as I want to keep the variable names same in both Modules.

Answer (score 1):

note that `@numNotes` is an instance variable, and belongs to object of corresponding class, not module
in other words, if you include both modules in your class there will be only one common `@numNotes` variable, and NOT two variables with the same name.

also, if I run your code, I get:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `majorNum' for #<ScaleDemo:0x007f8c528d6ef0>
```

so please correct example code to be exactly as yours

Comment: sorry if my example for confusing
below is correct replication of my issue
***********************
FILE name ABC.rb (path C:/my/ABC.rb)
module one
a= 10
end
                                                                    **************
FILE name DEF.rb (path C:/my/DEF.rb)
module two
   a=15
end
                                                                   **********                                                        FILE name MyClass.rb
require C:/my/DEF.rb
Class MyClass
  include two
  def  setup
  puts a
end
end
******************
result is 
10

Comment: you should put it in your question

Comment: thanks a lot for your inputs guys I have added a new example in my Question please have look and provide a solution really thankful Inder

Answer (score 0):

If you don't include `A`, `majorNum` won't be available; you are likely doing something incorrectly, or need to re-init your environment/class/etc.

That aside, what you're trying to do won't work: after mixing in, you have two modules that will attempt to define the same instance variable: whichever one is defined last will win.

How to solve it depends on your actual goal; if `ScaleDemo` is intended to represent a single scale, you'd ever only mix in a single version anyway (I'm not totally convinced a mix-in is the way to do this, but that's a different issue).

---

```
module One
 @@a = 10
end

module Two
 @@a = 15
end

class MyClass
 include Two

 def  setup
   puts @@a
 end
end

> c = MyClass.new
=> #<MyClass:0x94ab114>
> c.setup
15
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your inputs guys
I have added a new example in my Question
please have look and provide a solution 
really thankful
Inder

Comment: @user606011 That is *also* not your real code. Are you unable to cut-and-paste?

Comment: @user606011 Consider using a class variable instead; in order to have it be an instance variable you'd need to do more work, and this is already a bit beyond your level of expertise--keep it simple for now.

Comment: I agree to you dave. however my issue is that in my automation framework I have to inherit multiple modules (mixins) in one class. I have two application (who are quite similar with minimal code change) for whom the values keep on changing. Fist application data is in one set of modules and other has his data in second set of modules. Varibale names are same but value differ (30% of times). Class code is exactly the same just the set of modules I am including is different. changing variable names will consume a lot of time. ANY OTHER SOLUTION will be much appreciated--Thanks---Inder